# MySQL - How do I convert entire database into utf8

Tags: mysql, encoding, utf-8

I'm trying to figure out how to convert an entire database to utf8 and solve the following issue which results into having part of the data display incorrectly. At this point I'm simply confused and I need your insight. Here's some information you will probably need:

```
SHOW VARIABLES LIKE '%character%' returns:

Variable_name   Value
character_set_client    utf8
character_set_connection    utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem    binary
character_set_results   utf8
character_set_server    latin1
character_set_system    utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/
```

I'd like to convert ALL data to utf8 but I'm not sure how to perform this oreration or what might happen to the data (ie, malformed data, incorrect encoding).

Once I've finished the conversion, do I still need

```
header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8");
and mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'", $connection);
```

in my code?

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this will help:

http://www.oreillynet.com/onlamp/blog/2006/01/turning_mysql_data_in_latin1_t.html

Answer (score 1):

i would suggest you go with this little script to convert your data.
And make sure you have a fresh backup of you database.

```
<?php
// Database info

$dbhost = 'localhost';
$dbuser = 'db_user';
$dbpass = 'password';
$dbname = 'db_name';

//---------------

header('Content-type: text/plain');

$dbconn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass) or die( mysql_error() );
$db = mysql_select_db($dbname) or die( mysql_error() );

$sql = 'SHOW TABLES';
$result = mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );

while ( $row = mysql_fetch_row($result) )
{
  $table = mysql_real_escape_string($row[0]);
  $sql = "ALTER TABLE `$table` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci";
  mysql_query($sql) or die( mysql_error() );
  print "$table changed to UTF-8.\n";
}

mysql_close($dbconn);
?>
```

Comment: I tried your script but still I'm getting 

`character_set_client  utf8
character_set_connection  utf8
character_set_database  latin1
character_set_filesystem  binary
character_set_results  utf8
character_set_server  latin1
character_set_system  utf8
character_sets_dir  /usr/share/mysql/charsets/`

Comment: Export the data, drop the database and execute `CREATE DATABASE dbname CHARACTER SET utf8 COLLATE utf8_general_ci;` For `character_set_server latin` read in the mysql reference http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/charset-server.html

Comment: I cant do it in a script because I have limited privileges on the server. I can only create the db using Plesk UI.

Comment: As you just have limited access you only can execute those two querys: `set character_set_server=utf8;` and `set character_set_database=utf8;`. This will change these two variables at runtime. After server restart you will have to execute these querys once more